# There are 6 same apples and 8 same oranges. How many non-empty subset can be formed from those two kinds of fruits?

Tags: combinatorics

I thought it is $2^{14} - 1$ but I am not so sure. I think it is not a kind of multiplication principle, that is, $6 \cdot 8 = 48$, because in the context, the 6 apples are the same as well as the oranges.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your subsets $U_{a,o}$ is completely determined with number of apples $a$ and number
of oranges $o$ (it's not important which apples/oranges are in the set, because they are the same). Set $U_{a,o}$ is not empty iff $\max \{a,o\}>0$. You can choose $0\leq a \leq 6$ apples
and $0\leq o \leq 8$ oranges. The set $U_{0,0}$ is empty, so the answer is 
$$(6+1)\cdot (8+1) -1 = 62\text{.}$$